# REDHAWK IDL / jtrs-interfaces into Target SDR

Tags: linux, centos7, redhawksdr

Can anyone help me with how to install IDL Files into REDHAWK IDE Target SDR ? How to install and work with them in REDHAWK IDE.

I tried creating a new IDL from:https://github.com/rodrigo455/jtnc-interfaces

just by creating new IDL files and the copying the corresponding IDL into it but it came up with an error:Include file cannot be found: redhawk/VOCODER/Vocoder.idl

Please help me out if you got any solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way to add new interfaces is to use the custom IDL projects. To create a new custom IDL project, there are instructions here: https://redhawksdr.org/2.2.7/manual/ide/creating-redhawk-projects/

Creating and installing such a project with your IDL will make it possible to create a port that implements these interfaces: https://redhawksdr.org/2.2.7/manual/connections/custom-idl-interfaces/